# Constructor that receives an arbitrary amount of objects or an array of objects

Tags: c#, .net

I got next task:
Add constructor that receives an arbitrary amount of objects of type Rectangle or an array of objects of type Rectangle.

To solve it, I made two constructors. But if I understood correctly by the conditions of the problem, it should be one constructor. How to combine them? Or is it impossible?

```
public ArrayRectangles(IEnumerable<Rectangle> rectangles)
    {
        rectangle_array = rectangles.ToArray();
    }

    public ArrayRectangles(Rectangle[] rectangle_array)
    {
        this.rectangle_array = new Rectangle[rectangle_array.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < rectangle_array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (rectangle_array[i] != null)
            {
                this.rectangle_array[i] = new Rectangle(rectangle_array[i].GetSideA(), rectangle_array[i].GetSideB());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword:

> By using the `params` keyword, you can specify a method parameter that takes a variable number of arguments. The parameter type must be a single-dimensional array.

```cs
public ArrayRectangles(params Rectangle[] rectangle_array)
{
    ...
}
```

Which allows to call method (ctor in this case) either with array of `Rectangle` or variable number of `Rectangle` parameters:

```cs
var foo = new ArrayRectangles(new Rectangle[0]);
var bar = new ArrayRectangles(new Rectangle(), new Rectangle());
```